# Print PDF instead of page with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

on my wordpress-site i want to print a PDF in favor the html-content. Since I don't want to mess around with the theme I decided to embed this piece of code into the post.

My code (see below) works perfect (no errors in firebug) however when printing the post in firefox the webpage is printed and when printing in IE10 I only see the common header and footer in which I conclude it printed the PDF but was unable to view it.

```
function printPDF(pdfFile) {
$('link[media="print"]').remove();
$('style[media="print"]').remove();
$('head').append('<link href="'+ pdfFile + '" rel="alternate" type="application/pdf" title="PDF-versie" media="print" />');
}
```

Someone who can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since PDF is usually controlled by a plugin, you'd have to hook into the plugin to make it print properly. You might be able to force this to work using Mozilla's [PDF.js](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) on your site. It's built into Firefox, but you may be able to have it work with your site.